# Warble build fails due to C++ compiler not creating executables

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I'm working on installing the [MetaBase](https://mbientlab.com/tutorials/MetaBaseApp.html) dependencies for a project, but I cannot install either metawear or warble (which is the cause for the metawear installation to fail). The console log I have tells that the C++ compiler isn't properly setup, according to every other issue I could find online, but none of the proposed solutions have been effective. Here is the exact log for trying to run `sudo pip3 install warble` (starting from after package collection, which seems to have been successful. If needed, let me know):

```
 Installing collected packages: warble, metawear
  Running setup.py install for warble ... [?25l- \ | / error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-8sw2anxm/warble/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-abucfqdf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    make: Entering directory '/tmp/pip-build-8sw2anxm/warble/clibs/warble'
    mkdir -p build/arm/release/src/warble/cpp
    cd deps/libblepp; LDFLAGS=-marm ./configure
    mkdir -p dist/release/lib/arm
    g++ -MMD -MP -MF "build/arm/release/src/warble/cpp/lib.d" -c -o build/arm/release/src/warble/cpp/lib.o -std=c++14 -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -Werror -DWARBLE_DLL -DWARBLE_DLL_EXPORT -Isrc  -O3 -DAPI_BLEPP -Ideps/libblepp -marm src/warble/cpp/lib.cpp
    g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-marm’; did you mean ‘-fasm’?
    Makefile:84: recipe for target 'build/arm/release/src/warble/cpp/lib.o' failed
    make: *** [build/arm/release/src/warble/cpp/lib.o] Error 1
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
    configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-build-8sw2anxm/warble/clibs/warble/deps/libblepp':
    configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details
    Makefile:129: recipe for target 'deps/libblepp/Makefile' failed
    make: *** [deps/libblepp/Makefile] Error 77
    make: Leaving directory '/tmp/pip-build-8sw2anxm/warble/clibs/warble'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8sw2anxm/warble/setup.py", line 93, in <module>
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8sw2anxm/warble/setup.py", line 60, in run
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to compile libwarble.so")
    RuntimeError: Failed to compile libwarble.so
```

I see very clearly that the issue is:
`g++ checking whether the C++ compiler works... no`
`configure: error: in /tmp/pip-build-8sw2anxm/warble/clibs/warble/deps/libblepp':`
`configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables`

And I've followed several of the other answers I've found online, some suggesting to reinstall g++, check that /usr/bin/g++ exists and /usr/bin is in $PATH, all of which have made no change to this error. Is there somewhere else I need to look?

Edit: Here is the output of `uname -a` as requested:

> Linux WeFEI 4.9.140-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 27 21:02:46 PDT 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-marm’; did you mean ‘-fasm’?` looks suspiciously like a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: It's finding your native g++, but passing options that are more appropriate for a cross-compiler.  What architecture is your build computer?  Are you trying to cross-compile or do you expect everything to run on the computer where you are doing the build?

Comment: @BenVoigt the build is on an NVIDIA Jetson AGX Xavier running Ubuntu. Everything is going to be run off this computer, so what do I need to fix? I reinstalled the the compiler, so theoretically these are the default settings, unless I did something wrong (likely).

Comment: So that's definitely an ARM processor, not sure whether 64-bit or not.  Which means that it is entirely appropriate for the build to be happening in the `arm` subdirectory (do check if there is a separate directory for arm-64 though).  Probably worth showing the output from `g++ --dumpmachine` in your question.

Comment: Note that G++ calls arm-64 "AArch64" and its options are here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html#AArch64-Options  The `-marm` option exists only on 32-bit arm and not on AArch64.  This is likely your problem, build options for 32-bit arm and a 64-bit arm system and compiler.

Comment: I recommend also showing the `uname -a` output so we can see whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit ARM kernel running.

Comment: My suspicion is that somewhere along the way (maybe `pip3` settings) you were asked to choose your target architecture and you chose `arm` when you should have selected `AArch64`

Comment: @BenVoigt I appreciate the help thus far. I've added the uname -a output to the bottom of the post. How would I swap the target architecture for pip (or whatever else it would be)?